# Exchange EWS Calendar AppointmentState

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using EWS against Exchange 2010 SP1.

I am trying to retrieve a list of appointments that have been neither accepted or declined. I thought AppointmentState may be the field i was looking for, but this does not seem to be the correct field (see links), does anyone know where i can find if a appointment has been accepted or declined?
**AppointmentState** 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment_members(v=exchg.80).aspx]
**AppointmentState Definition**
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa564700(v=exchg.140).aspx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after further research it appears that this is not the field you need to look at. the RequiredAttendee sand OptionalAttendees collections is where it's at, as detailed here:

[EWS-manged: Fetch required and optional attendees of appointments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473165/ews-manged-fetch-required-and-optional-attendees-of-appointments)

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the appointment was accepted or declined in the [MyResponseType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564248(v=exchg.150).aspx) poperty.

This will have one of the following values:

- Unknown - Response status is unknown
- Organizer - The item owner is the meeting organizer
- Tentative - The item owner accepted tentatively
- Accept - The item owner accepted
- Decline - The item owner declined
- NoResponseReceived - The item owner did not yet respond to the invitation

The values are explained a little better in the documentation of the property in the [EWS managed API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.responsetypetype(v=exchg.150).aspx).